# How to append elements with children elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I'm familiar with the preferred method of creating elements with jQuery:

```
jQuery('<div/>', {
    id: 'foo',
    href: 'http://google.com',
}).appendTo('#mySelector');
```

But I need to create some elements with that are a little more complex than what the above does. Is there a way I can build my code so that it outputs something like:

```
<div id="foo" href="http://google.com"> 
   <h1> Heading </h1>
   <div id="child-div">
      Conetent created from jQuery vars
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You can add it as a big string `jQuery('big_html_string_here').appendTo('#mySelector');`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simple pass the html string to the jQuery function

```
jQuery('<div id="foo" href="http://google.com"><h1> Heading </h1><div id="child-div">Conetent created from jQuery vars</div></div>')
.appendTo('#mySelector');
```

or create each element individually

```
jQuery('<div/>', {
    id: 'foo',
    href: 'http://google.com',
})
.append('<h1/>', {text: ' Heading '})
.append('<div/>', {id: 'child-div', text: 'Conetent created from jQuery vars'})
.appendTo('#mySelector');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create elements directly inside the jQuery function.

Example:

```
$("<div></div>");
```

Will create a div element and upgrade the DOM collection.

Answer (score 0):

it could be something like this:

```
var html = '<div id="foo">';
html += '  <h1>Heading</h1>';
html += '  <div id="child-div">';
html += '    <p>'+myVar+'</p>';      //Content created from jQuery vars
html += '  </div>';
html += '</div>';
$('#mySelector').append( html );
```

You can declare the your `html` variable in one line, but I prefer these multiline way becuse of its clarity.

Remember that you cannot add [`href`](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_href.asp) to div element!